# How to print an array in upper case using tr///

Tags: perl, tr

```
my @array = qw( one two three four five six seven );
my $arr = \@array;
# $arr=~ tr/,(a-z)/\t(A-Z)/;
print uc(join(' ', @array)), "\n";
```

**output**

```
ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN
```

But I want the same output using `tr///`.

Comment: Why would you want to use tr/// and have to know how to uppercase everything when uc() already knows that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `(a-z)` with `a-z` and perform `tr///` for each element of `@array`

```
my @array = qw(one two three four five six seven);

tr/a-z/A-Z/ for @array;
print join(' ',@array), "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.can you tell me, `->` why we use this operator in perl?

Comment: can you give me one example for that?

Comment: `my$str = 'aa bbb c dd eee ff mmmm rr' ;
$str =~tr/abcd/1234/;
print $str,"\n";` it showing `11 222 3 44 eee ff mmmm rr`.how to remove unmatched  string in my output

Comment: i tried but it's not working.I'm getting same output.please tel me

Comment: ` 'This pencil is .... old. You can ..... it .....';` in this how to count this dots.please let me

Comment: but how to get desire output using `tr///`

Comment: `tr///` doesn't accept regular expressions, and so doesn't use character classes. `tr/,[a-z]/\t[A-Z]/` works only because it is replqacing `[` with `[` and `]` with `]`.

Comment: @user3114045: You shouldn't be asking additional questions in the comments. (And `mpapec`, you shouldn't be answering them!) Post anything else you have to ask as new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Use map function

```
@array = qw(one two three four five six seven);
@for=map{uc$_}@array;
print "@for \n";
```

Answer (score -1):

It's far from clear what you want. Since you have a solution, why do you want to use `tr` instead? Is this a homework assignment?

Because `tr` returns the *number of characters translated*, you have to `join` the elements of the array into a separate variable and then translate that to upper case.

This program shows a working example.

By the way, please *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of *every* program you write, especially if you are asking for help with your code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @array = qw( one two three four five six seven );

my $arr = join ' ', @array;
$arr =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;
print $arr, "\n";
```

**output**

```
ONE TWO THREE FOUR FIVE SIX SEVEN
```